# rxjava behaviour of onErrorResumeNext

Tags: android, rx-java, system.reactive

I am having trouble getting Observer.onErrorResumeNext to behave as i would expect.

```
Subscriber orchestratorObserver = new Subscriber<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("orchestratorObserver."+"onCompleted()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("orchestratorObserver."+"onError()"+e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("orchestratorObserver."+"onNext() : "+i);
    }
};

@Test
public void rxTest() {
    Observable.range(0,5)
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Integer integer) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("chain error!!");
                }
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(-1))
            .subscribe(orchestratorObserver);
}

@Test
public void rxTest1() {

    final Observable<Integer> errorTrainObservable = Observable.defer(
            new Func0<Observable<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Integer> call() {
                    return Observable.error(new RuntimeException("source error"));
                }
            });

    errorTrainObservable.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(-1));

    errorTrainObservable.subscribe(orchestratorObserver);
}
```

so rxTest() outputs:

```
orchestratorObserver.onNext() : -1
orchestratorObserver.onCompleted()
```

while rxTest1() outputs:

```
orchestratorObserver.onError()source error
```

I would like rxTest1 to output the same onNext event as rxTest - how can I do that? i.e. I want to swallow the error and emit a defualt value onNext event.

It seem odd that if the error is at the source it behaves one way - but if the error is the chain it behaves another way? Extra points if you can explain that to me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines:

```
errorTrainObservable.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(-1));

errorTrainObservable.subscribe(orchestratorObserver);
```

You create an `Observable` with an error handler, then you throw it away, then you subscribe to the observable without the error handler.